# RS-232 Level Shifter

Tags: level-shifting, rs232, ttl

Most PCs don't have RS232 built-in anymore. So the only option is USB-2-RS232 adapters or RS232 PCI-E card. While I expected the adapters to output a low voltage it turns out most RS232 PCI-E card also just output +/-5V. In order to increase distance I need to boost the +/-5V to somewhere in the range of +/-12V. I did a lot of googling but all I kind find is TTL to RS232 (many outputting the +/-12V but my input is not TTL but +/-5V).

So how can I level shift a +/-5V signal to a +/-12V signal?

Comment: Level-shift the ±5V RS232 signal back to 0-5V, then level-shift it to ±12V again. Use e.g. a MC1488, a MC1489 and a ±12V supply to do the trick.

Comment: Use anything ***but*** an 1488 and 1489. Those are 1970's technology, require \$\pm\$ voltage rails, and the 1488 itself will burn close to 3/4 watt all by itself just sitting idle. I've used them and they work great. But cripes those things are hot to the touch!! However, if you are building an RS-232 connected hand-warmer, then by all means consider them.

Comment: jonk, what would you use instead of the MC1488 or MC1489?

Comment: "to increase distance" ... consider using an RS485 USB adapter instead, and an RS-232 to RS-485 adapter if the far end is actually RS-232.